# How do I use an animated GIF image for the Windows 8.1 lock screen?

Tags: windows, windows-8, lock-screen, animated-gif

I know how to set an image file (`.gif` format in this case) on Windows 8.1 lock screen, but by some reason the image is shown as "static" instead of "animated".

How do I use an animated GIF as a lock screen image?

I want to use an image like this:

[image: streaming spiral spectrum]

Comment: This won't be possible. When you select a image for the lock screen Windows is only capable of processing the first frame in the .gif format.